# How can i write something to file at the end of the file in c++

Tags: c++, file

i'm writing something to file and it writes it in the middle of the file, is there any function that writes output to the end of the file? thanx in advance.
ok this is really wierd i'm running with the visual studio debugger and i see that it writes thing to file like this :
A
B
C
D
which is good, and than when i'm writing something for example E it writes it here
A
B
E
C
D
this is really wierd, how can i fix it?

Comment: Why would it write in the middle of the file and not at the start or end? Is the file being opened by something else?

Comment: Please post a brief but complete compilable code sample that exhibits the problem.

Comment: i solved it, i invoked the function at a wrong time, thanx for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `std::ofstream` and open the file in append mode (using `std::ios_base::app` in the mode mask) then all writes will be made at the end of the file.

Comment: i did what you said and still it prints things to the middle of the file :(

Comment: @Roy Gavrielov: Then either you have buggy code or a buggy implementation. Without seeing your code it's impossible to say which is the case.

Answer (score 2):

With the plain old C functions, `open` the file with `O_APPEND` or call `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)` before writing.

With `ofstream`, call `file.seekp(0, ios_base::end)` before writing.

Comment: i can't, my file is ofstream, any other way?